# How to print a String in a Label

Tags: visual-studio

I want to mix the sting and free text in a label

Exempel:

```
String inst = "Installing:";

            label1.Text = Inst;
```

This Works,but If i want to mix the sting "inst" with a text of my own i don't know how.

Exempel 2:

```
      String Inst = "Installing:";

    label1.Text = inst, "Google Chrome";
```

This is how I thought the code would look like, but no

Comment: This is called string concatenation and could be obtained using the [string.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx) method or just using the + operator between the two strings (Inst + "Google Chrome")

Comment: Which programming language is this? C/C++? Because the `,` for string concattenation looks nothing like C/C++ ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if your looking for C#

```
String Inst = "Installing:";
label1.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}",inst, "Google Chrome");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try it with:

```
label1.Text = inst + "Google Chrome";
```

I think this would work.

Comment: Maybe use a `_T` in case the project is either an ASCII or UNICODE?